# PHP preg match regular expression faced with strange symbol from swedish alphabet

Tags: php, regex

In php 7.3.14 I have string name `Brick Red 140`. From that string I want to fetch all without digit, I work with swedish language and for that I omplemented this `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z ¤æøĂÂéëäöåÉÄÖÅ]+/',$color,$matches)
```

and in some case I faced with strange error, in `$matches` I faced with some uncoded symbol

```
$matches = {array} [1]
 0 = {array} [1]
  0 = "Brick Red�"
```

after test, I executed `utf8_encode`

```
utf8_encode($mat[0][0])
```

and got `Brick RedÂ`. Why space transform to `Â` and how to resolve it right ? Maybe change regual expression or something like that ?

Comment: That little question mark, a box for other cases, means that there's no equivalent for the unicode point you are trying to represent in the encoding you are using. There are hundreds of encodings which can only store some code points correctly  and change the all other code points into question marks.

Comment: It could have to do with the multibyte characters. Add the `u` modifier to the regex `/[a-zA-Z ¤æøĂÂéëäöåÉÄÖÅ]+/u`. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure why your matches include that strange character. I can only guess it's to do with your regular expression.

But if you're wanting to get all strings that aren't a digit, you can use this:

`preg_match_all('/[^\d]+/',$color,$matches)`

`$matches` would contain:

```
['Brick Red ']
```

If you wanted all words separately, you could use:

`preg_match_all('/[^\d\s]+/',$color,$matches)`

`$matches` would contain:

```
['Brick', 'Red']
```

Comment: hm, yes, it's help, but what about different symbol like `¤æøĂÂéëäöåÉÄÖÅ` ? They will be match too without problem ?

Comment: I've just done a test on https://regex101.com/ and it seemed to work for me.  It will collect any characters that aren't a digit (i.e. 0-9). `\d` is the token for any digit. `^` negates a group of characters. So this regular expression matches any character that is NOT a digit.